# Turning off captcha in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

i want to get rid of filling a query form on daily basis and want to automate it. But it is having captcha and i want to turn off captcha so that i can automate form using selenium webdriver using python.

Comment: Do you need to *use* Selenium to respond to the captcha then fill in the form, or do you need to stop the captcha appearing at all?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-test-automation?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why websites have captcha is to prevent robots accessing the website. If it's for testing purposes ask the devs to provide you with a url that bypasses the captcha.